# Equal loudness per frequency

Tags: c#, naudio, synthesizer

So I'm coding a synthesizer from scratch in C# using NAudio. I've gotten it play different  frequencies, which is cool, but I notice that the higher pitches are significantly louder than the lower pitches. Is that due to this effect:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour

Or am I doing something wrong when I'm generating the sine wave? How would I implement an Equal-loudness contour curve if it is indeed necessary?

Thanks

My Code:

NAudio expects a buffer filled with floating point values in the range of -1 to +1 to represent the waveform.

**Generating the sine wave:**

```
buffer[n + offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin(angle));
angle = (angle + angleIncrement) % (2 * Math.PI);
```

**Setting a frequency:**

```
public double Frequency
{
    set
    {
        angleIncrement = 2 * Math.PI * value / sampleRate;
    }
    get
    {
        return angleIncrement * sampleRate / 2 / Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok (so long as `Amplitude` is constant).

Comment: `Amplitude` would represent how loud the user wants to play the note. It's constant for now in my testing. That being the case, do you think I need to implement a loudness contour/

Comment: I already posted: "The human ear doesn't work like that, it is highly non-linear."  The scale on the left of that graph is logarithmic, 3 dB equals a factor of 2.

Comment: Are you playing it through PC speakers?  They don't do bass so well.  It might sound more even you if saved an MP3 file and played it through a real stereo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling the amplitude of the audio from your synthesizer based on equal-loudness contours is probably *not* what you want.

In theory, you would need to know the absolute level (SPL) produced by the speakers in order to choose the appropriate contour. In practice, a bigger issue would be when you extend your synthesizer to use complex waveforms instead of merely pure tones, possibly processed by filters etc. The equal-loudness contours are based on pure tones, and when you generate complex signals (i.e. containing many frequencies) you would instead need a loudness model to estimate the loudness of your synthesized sound.